# Code in Vue watch changes the data which is watched, resulting in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently I have a button which simply changes one of the properties inside chartData. I also have a watch that watches for any changes ( including nested ones ) and if there are any changes, it renders a new chart. Then the new render of the new chart sets `this.chartObject = new Chart` which I believe triggers the Vue watch again and starts the infinite loop.

Any way to avoid this?

Button which changes the data:

```
<button @click='addChartData()'>Add Data</button>
```

Data:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        chartData: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6],
                label: 'My First dataset'
            }]
        },
        chartObject: null
    }
}
```

Methods

```
methods: {
    renderChart(chartData, chartOptions){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        this.chartObject = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartData,
            options: chartOptions
        });
    },
    addChartData(){
        this.$set(this.chartData, 'labels', ['Red', 'Blue'])
        console.log(this.chartData)
    }
},
```

And finally the watch:

```
watch: {
        'chartData.labels': function(newValue, oldValue){
            this.chartObject.destroy()
            this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions)
            console.log('Changed')
        },
}
```

Comment: With what you have provided, it is impossible to reproduce/debug the issue, since we don't know what `Chart` class is/does and we haven't been shown the ctx `<canvas>`. Therefore, your question cannot be answered. Please provide a [mcve].